# building a table of images

Tags: tables, graphics, cjk

I seem to have run into an impassable issue that I need help solving, and I am 100% aware that this is impossible just pure LaTeX but I wish it was. So onto the question at hand.

I am wanting to build a table of images, in this case they are eps's of 11,251 kanji.
now from the start I looked into how to loop files in LaTex, as I did not want to manually type in all 11,251. And found out that without any help from a shell script its impossible, so  I cobbled together this

```
for f in *.eps; do echo "\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{./Reference/kanji/eps/$f}" >> ../eps.list; done
```

It was just for a start and it worked amazingly, the only issue now is that LaTeX is not playing nice with that list. it throws errors such as `Number too big ...=0.25]{./Reference/kanji/eps/0002e.svg.eps}` and `Dimension too large ...=0.25]{./Reference/kanji/eps/0002e.svg.eps}` they are only 512x512 so Im assuming that means the bounding box is too big, As a note on the eps' they where converted from SVG's with the following script

`for f in *.svg; do inkscape -f $f -D -E $f.eps -z; done`

And it only took about 58 minutes to run so my life could be worse. The main thing that i am asking assistance with is how to generate the table. it would need be 6 columns across by N rows down and fill the slots sequentially, that I have no idea about how to go about, so if you would be so kind as to assist me in that.

Another issue that i might as well bring up is that i seem to be having mountains of trouble with the CJK package, after several hours of looking here and elsewhere I have completed the fonts and rebuilt the font DB updated everything and it still dies with `Undefined control sequence 縲梧律` and a metric nut ton of `Undefined control sequence 縲梧律` Errors, the Main file looks like so

```
\documentclass[UTF8,14pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{CJK}
\newcommand{\bookversion}{v0.0 REV 0}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
\input{Title}
\clearpage
「日本語」
\tableofcontents
\include{Introduction/Part.Introduction}
\include{Learn/Part.Learn}
\include{Reference/Part.Reference}
\clearpage
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

As mentioned before I am at a loss on multiple ends, my apologies for the huge wall of text and I thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's hard to know where to start.

You say you think the boundingbox is too big. I assume they are all the same, what is the `%%BoundingBox` line in the EPS (and are they all the same?)

It could (I think) be that you are just generating a line that is too long. You appear to be making a list of `\includegraphics{}` commands 11251 long with no commands in between. To TeX an included graphic is basically like a letter and so it is like going

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....
```

with one very long non-breakable line.

Modify your shell script to write

```
for f in *.eps; do echo "\do\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{./Reference/kanji/eps/$f}" >> ../eps.list; done
```

so now you have `\do` in front of each.

If you say `\let\do\par` before including the image list each image will be in its own paragraph, which is much lighter on TeX memory. That isn't the layout you want but it is a good test to see if the errors change in that case.

To get six images in a row you can define

```
\newcount\imgcount

\def\do{%
\advance\imgcount 1 
\ifnum\imgcount=7
\par
\imgcount=0
\else
\space
\fi}
```

That would put a space between each image and start a new paragraph every 6 (vertical alignment would be automatic as they are all the same size so you don't need a table construct.