# How to calculate the number of cells per line

Tags: tables, calculations

Assume I have a table with a dynamic number of rows and columns, and I want to fill the table with n elements. Assume an element has the constant length x, and I want to say make floor(linewitdth/x) columns per row so that the maximal number of elements is in a row. How would I write that in LaTeX?

Comment: LaTeX tables don't have a dynamical number of columns. The elements of the table are saved in a `csv` file? I think the package `datatool` will be the best choice.

Comment: No, the data comes in as a string, thats the problem....

Comment: Counting the elements of a string is really simple. Please provide a minimal example. The elements are separated by comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your elements all have the same width *x*  (either naturally or because you put each one in a `\makebox[3cm][l]{.....}` ) then you don't need a table construct or to do any arithmetic, just place them one after another in a `flushleft` environment and the paragraph breaker will naturally fit as many as it can on each line, and vertical alignment is automatic.

See this technique being used

[building a table of images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68398/building-a-table-of-images/68402#68402)

or

[enumerate in multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67966/enumerate-in-multicols/67983#67983)

Comment: ok, this looks promisingg, last stupid question - for a given string x, how do i determine the width and put it in your formula?